# Talend Component for Creating XSD from a XML File

Tags: talend

I have a XML file with me with Data in the file.
I am Looking for a Component in Talend which can create a XSD file for me from the XML input.
There are online Utility to do it (freeformatter.com/xsd-generator), however is there a component in Talend ?

Answer (score 1):

In Talend , no xsdoutput .

If what you need is a scheme , you can play and get the XML schema with METADATA.

XML and XSD are usually supplemented in the same file .

Once done, you can use the XSD generation or Oxygen.

Answer (score 0):

We can try **tAdvancedOutputXML** component of talend.
Here we can use following advanced setting

Advanced setting >> Create associated XSD file.

or 
 Here you can have the details about component

"https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide521EN/22.1+tAdvancedFileOutputXML"